# How to find the files of specific file types using shell script

Tags: shell

I want to find the specific file types in a particular directory. Once the file type got matched I need to delete the file. As I have used the below codes but it does not work. Could you suggest solution for this?

```
directory=/var/log/myFiles

if [ -d $directory ]
then
   for file in $directory/*
      do  
       if [ -f $file ]
       then    
         if [$file==*.log.1]
         then
            rm file            
        fi
       fi
      done 
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a script, find + exec could do that:

```
find /var/log/myFiles -name "*.log.1" -exec echo rm {} \;
```

Your script fails:

```
$ ./script.sh
./script.sh: line 11: [/var/log/myFiles/a==*.log.1]: No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 11: [/var/log/myFiles/a.log.1==*.log.1]: No such file or directory
```

because the `if` line is completely wrong, it should be something
like:

```
if [[ "$file" == *.log.1 ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have implemented your code in Jenkins FreeStyle job with the Shell Script option. But I have faced an error while *.log1 file does not exist in the directory. 
In my case, whether the file should exist in the directory, it will delete. if the file does not exist directory the Jenkins job should not be failed. Could you please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Sure but please edit your question first to let everyone know that your requirements have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter and faster solution is using `find` and `xargs`:

```
find /var/log/myFiles -type f -name '*.log.1' | xargs rm
```

---

Before doing mass deletes like the above, I do a safety check first, like so:

```
find /var/log/myFiles -type f -name '*.log1' | xargs ls -1
```

---

If your files contain spaces or newlines, use `NUL`-delimited form of the command above:

```
find /var/log/myFiles -type f -name '*.log.1' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```